# Using Scons to build Alljoyn Thin App for Arduino

Tags: arduino, scons, alljoyn

I am trying to get familiar with Alljoyn Thin Core Library (15.09) and my current goal is to run the example from AJTCL_DIR\src\target\arduino\examples\AJ_LedService. The problem is I am not familiar with the Scons and there seems to be no guide for building AJTCL for arduino target (Arduino + freeRTOS is not what I need). Can anyone help me with building that library for Arduino, because my attempts to buid that with scons failed.[scons buid output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCqPI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the way to solve this problem was to edit file Sconscript.target.arduino.
I replaced these lines:

```
`# Install the .c files as .cpp files for the Arduino IDE to consume.
srcs = [
    Glob('src/*.c'),
    Glob('src/target/$TARG/*.c'),
    Glob('src/crypto/*.c'),
    Glob('external/sha2/*.c')
]`
```

with following:

```
`# Install the .c files as .cpp files for the Arduino IDE to consume.
srcs = []
srcs.extend(Glob('src/*.c'))
srcs.extend(Glob('src/target/$TARG/*.c'))
srcs.extend(Glob('src/crypto/*.c'))
srcs.extend(Glob('external/sha2/*.c'))`.
```

So list `srcs` contains file objects, not the list of file objects. After applying these changes lib was build successfully, but i stil have some problems with compilation.

Answer (score 0):

In the "SConscript.target.arduino" file, change the variable with the correct path.

```
arduinoLibDir = '#dist/arduino_due/libraries/AllJoyn/'
```

Try;

```
scons WS=off VARIANT=debug TARG=arduino
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure if the builds(working) for Arduino are available yet. There is some work going on, to get the Arduino builds running.

here is the link to one of mails on the Allseen Core Working List.
[Allseen Core Mailing List](https://lists.allseenalliance.org/pipermail/allseen-core/2015-September/002471.html)

I had tried to build them, even thought it built successfully i still had a few unreferenced libraries and hence the AJ_LedService example would not compile.!

Comment: Here is [a link](https://jira.allseenalliance.org/browse/ASACORE-2120) to allSeen aliance jira's page. It says, that bug must have been fixed. 
Also another interesting [link](https://ask.allseenalliance.org/question/784/new-to-aj-help-with-ajtcl-arduino-due/)? where user tells, that he obtained successful build.

Comment: @Vadimchik the above links  - jira page link last updated - 09-09-2015 and the second link about the user is July 2014 and the link I posted is from 11-09-2015, so I am assuming that there are still some issues. I had written a mail on the mailing list in Jan-2016 but did not get a reply yet.